# query builder join and get the specified record laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm joing two table and then find the specified record but unfortunately it doesnt work.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_details.id')
        //->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
        ->get()->find(1);
```

any ideas help?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using Eloquent?

Comment: im not yet good at it. Im using both eloqouent and query builder but as of now, im using query builder for this issue. If you could suggest achieiving it using eloqouent then would love have yours.

Comment: What do you mean specific record?

Comment: like i want to grab the record that match to the give id.

Comment: What parameter you are passing? The id of users?

Comment: yes the id of the user

Comment: Can i see the controller of that?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this using Eloquent, do the following:

*I'm assuming you're using the latest Laravel version (5.1)*

**1. You need a Model for the User and the UserDetails:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {}
```

**2. Set up the relationship between them**

*User.php*

```
function details()
{
    // for this to work, the user_details table needs a column user_id
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserDetail');
}
```

*UserDetail.php*

```
function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**3. Query the relationship:**

*e.g. UserController.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

class UserController {
    public function index()
    {
        $user = User::find(1);
        $user_details = $user->details;

        // or

        $user = User::find(1)->with('details');

    }
}
```

Comment: so how im going to query it then after i done the set up for there relationship?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it in my first answer. Please see my edited one.

Comment: nice. My user table has id not user_id, same also to the uses_detals the primary key  column has a named of "id" is that okay? how im going to work with it as you said it must have "user_id"

Comment: You can specify the foreign key when defining relationships like this: `$this->hasMany('App\UserDetail`, 'foreign_key');`
Just replace `foreign_key` with `id` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the correct query will be like below:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->find(1)
    ->join('user_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_details.id')
    ->get();
```

Or you can use `where` to specify where clauses.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->where('user.gender', '=', 1) // Example.
    ->join('user_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_details.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: unfortunately, I got this error "Call to undefined method stdClass::join()" any ideas? im using the first code from your answer.

Comment: and I got this error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` inner join `user_details` on `users`.`id` = `user_details`.`id` where `user`.`id` = 1)" after I tried the second one, any ideas?

Comment: @CodeDemon Post your table schema too within your question

Comment: I add only example. You need to specify your fields to query builder.

Comment: It's the easiest way. But better solution - to use laravel relationship.